# Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

```
root@ip-10-131-9-200:/etc/php5/apache2# php -a
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Interactive shell
```

Answer (score 142):

Even though several other answers suggest it, installing more unnecessary software is generally **not** the best solution. Instead, you should fix the underlying problem. The reason these messages appear is because you are trying to load those extensions, but they are not installed. So the easy solution is simply to tell PHP to stop trying to load them:

First, find out which files are trying to load the above extensions:

```
$ grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -E "extension(\s+)?="
```

Example output for Ubuntu:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini:extension=gd.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_sqlite.ini:extension=pdo_sqlite.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini:extension=pdo.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini:extension=pdo_mysql.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini:extension=mysql.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini:extension=curl.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/sqlite3.ini:extension=sqlite3.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini:extension=mcrypt.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini:extension=imagick.so
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:extension=http.so
```

Now just find the files that are loading the extensions that are causing the errors and comment out those lines with a `;`. For some reason this happened to me with the default install of Ubuntu, so hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: I encountered the same errors after a dist-upgrade from Debian 6.x to 7.1. I didn't know `suhosin` and `idn` modules got removed in this newer packages.. so big thx for the nice `grep` line.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked pretty fine in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I yet have a question: If I disable the extensions causing the error by placing a ; symbol at the beggining of the line, will they be re-enabled after an upgrade?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo When upgrading, sometimes it will prompt you whether to overwrite the config file. If you overwrite it, it MAY overwrite these ones, but I'm not too sure. Just choose no.

Comment: I agree, if you don't need it the extension why install it?

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 12.04, update PHP 5.3.x -> 5.4.x) I had to remove the conf file associated to the extension in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/

Comment: I like this kind of answers because they make you understand what's going on AKA = know-how

Comment: i like this answer too BUT, re: "but they are not installed" comment by Mike isn't always 100% true. My php.ini file had a common config: `extension_dir = "./usr/lib64/php/modules"`, but when i tried to run php at the prompt (ex: `#php my_file.php`) it would trigger this error because it points to a RELATIVE path. By changing the setting to `extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"` (without the preceding dot) i no longer received this error, because the modules were indeed installed, and could now be found when running php from anywhere on my server.

Comment: This regex is not applicable on all case, for exemple in Newrelic .ini file they are spaces around equal sign: `/etc/php5/mods-available/newrelic.ini:extension = "newrelic.so"`

Comment: is controversial, altough this answer helped a lot of people should also explain how to fix it when really we need the extension, that's my case. I need that extensión loaded and this doesn't help me :S

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 I had to go to `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` to comment out those lines.

Answer (score 47):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

...etc resolved it for me :)

hope it helps

Comment: Your answer got my site working again!  thank you so much, I really appreciate this.  I have spend hours on this. I followed some instructions to upgrade mysql and they must have omitted this part.

Answer (score 13):

Look /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ and delete corresponding *.ini files. This error happens when you remove some php packages not so cleanly.

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you **upgraded PHP** to newer version and old .ini files are still pointing to old location.

**The solution**: find out where are modules located now

```
ls -l /usr/lib/php5
```

There should be a directory similar to old `20090626`. In my case it is now `20131226`

The .ini files giving you an error are located at `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/`

Just edit those .ini files which module gives you an error. For example, in case the error is for mcrypt module:

```
sudo vi /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Change the line:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so
```

to reflect the new path for .so file. In my case the correct path should be:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so
```

That's it! The error is gone. Ofc you'd have to do it with each module giving you an error.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the ; symbol, this  action inactive the extension.

I had the same problem and did the following:

1. Uninstall php with purge parameter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-common
   ```
2. And install again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql
   ```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

I have

- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
- Ubuntu Desktop 12.04
- Mysql 5.5

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution by [blog.tordeu.com](http://blog.tordeu.com/), and it's

```
sudo aptitude purge php5-suhosin
```

I'm not sure, but it seems that the `suhosin` is no longer needed, it worked for my, my PHP version:

```
PHP 5.4.34-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2014 15:26:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 5.6 php,

sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl

Comment: i installed for 7.* php with command: sudo apt-get install php-curl

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `gmp.so` file seems to have been deleted from my system.  This is what fixed it for me:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-gmp`

Answer (score 0):

Well for Ubuntu 14.04 I was getting that error just for mcrypt:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.ini' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.ini: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

If you have a closer look at the error, php is looking for mcrypt.ini and not for mcrypt.so at that location. I just copy mcrypt.so to mcrypt.ini and that's it, the warning is gone and the extension now is properly installed. It might look a bit dirty but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had enabled the extension_dir in php.ini by uncommenting,

```
  extension_dir = "ext"
  extension=phpchartdir550.dll
```

and copying phpchartdir550 dll to the extension_dir (/usr/lib/php5/20121212),  resulted in the same error.

```
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/phpchartdir550.dll' - ext/phpchartdir550.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/pdo.so' - ext/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/gd.so' - ext/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

As @Mike pointed out, it is not necessary to install all the stuff when they are not actually required in the application.

The easier way is to provide the full path to the extensions to be loaded after copying the libraries to the correct location.

Copy phpchartdir550.dll to /usr/lib/php5/20121212, which is the extension_dir in my Ubuntu 14.04 (this can be seen using phpinfo())
and then provide full path to the library in php.ini,

```
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/phpchartdir550.dll
```

restart apache: sudo service apache2 restart

even though other .so's are present in the same directory, only the required ones can be selectively loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which led me here:

```
$ phpunit --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/profiler.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/profiler.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHPUnit 5.7.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Unlike the above, installing the software did not resolve my problem because I already had it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-uprofiler
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-uprofiler is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
```

I found my solution via : [Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784774)

```
$ sudo vim /etc/php5/mods-available/uprofiler.ini
```

I edited the ini file, changing *extension=profiler.so* to *extension=uprofiler.so* .... the result, happily:

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 5.7.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

i.e. no more warning.

Answer (score 0):

(For Ubuntu users)

I had the same problem, but none of the answers above solved that. Here is how I solved the problem.

Open your `php.ini` file (mine was in `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini`).

You may have something like this:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Or maybe:

```
extension=/here/is/the/path/to/your/file/pdo_mysql.so
```

Add the following line before `extension=pdo_mysql`

```
extension=pdo
```

So, you will have:

```
extension=pdo
extension=pdo_mysql
```

It seems that the problem is (at least in my case) that we need to load `pdo` extension first to load the `pdo_mysql` extension.

Hope that helps!