# PHP 'Unable to load dynamic library... procedure not found'

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-extension, dynamic-library

This is my first day with Zend Framework with appServ and i used NetBeans IDE, but i got this error.

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'G:/PROGRA~2/AppServ\php5\ext\php_exif.dll' - The specified procedure
>   could not be found.

I am surprised cause this file already exists when i serached on google i found that i can solve this by change the order of extensions in php.ini and put the ;extension=php_exif.dll at the ends of other. but the error still.

help me plz;

Comment: You get shocked when you win the lottery. You're surprised (or annoyed) when a file isn't found.

Comment: thank you but if you have an answer plz help,

Comment: Marc B -- your correction seems neurotypical-centric to me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Answer (score 0):

You must load php_mbstring.dll **before** the php_exif.dll.

Comment: :thank you but i'm change the order of extension and i placed the php_exif.dll at the end of extensions list in php.ini

Comment: i'm used appserv-win32-2.5.10 and ZendFramework-1.11.12-minimal, when write zf command "Entry point Not Found" error appear say "the procedure entry point zend_wrong_param_count could not be located in the dynamic link library php4ts.dll but i have php5ts.dll . Is zendFramework version can't work correctly with appserv?