# Error loading pdo_mysql in php built-in server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to run php's built-in server (running by `$ php -S localhost:8888`) with PDO extension.
But when I type this command into terminal it gives me:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
```

(And when I try to use it it says that `PDO class not found`)

The same is when I run just `$ php`. But when I start apache2 server everything looks good (the PDO extension is working).

And the file `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so` exists.

Thanks for your answers!

(running php 5 on ubuntu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've finally solved by reinstalling php:

1. Uninstall php with purge parameter:

   `sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-common`
2. And install again:

   `sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php5-curl` etc...

Source: [Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: This was a life saver for me