# Unable to load dynamic library; cannot open shared object file

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-5

When I use `php artisan migrate:rollback` with Laravel 5, I get this error:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so' -
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll'
>   - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> ---
>
> - Application In Production!     *
>
>   ---
>
> Do you really wish to run this command? [y/N]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because those libraries are not in: `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/`

First, check if those files exist on your server and change to the right path.
Second, if they are not in your server, you need to install them.

I am not sure which OS you are using, but this is how you do it in Ubuntu / Mint

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Usually XAMPP contains this library. It might be a bad installation, path change or file manipulation issue as well. In these cases, try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I've tried to run my shell command prompt in my xampp control, It works like magic, just go to xampp control, click the shell button, and type the directories where your file is located, type php artisan serve Hope this help.