# PHP installation 5.6.7

Tags: php, installation

While upgrading php from php.5.3.25 to php5.6.7. got the below errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so' - /opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ffmpeg.so' - /opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so' - /opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: are u using Ubuntu??

Comment: You might need to have a question in order for someone to answer it.

Comment: I am using Red Hat enterprise Linux 5.10.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to load those extensions which are not installed.Try this for installation in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

[FOR MORE REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: I am using RHEL 5.10. I tried using the sudo app-get, but this does not work. Do I need to install the these extension separately? Secondly I am not able to find any entry made in the php.ini file where it is written to get the extensions from the no-debug-non-zts-20131226 directory. There is one more directory no-debug-non-zts-20001296 which has the .so files for the above extensions.