# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, cygwin, tidy, dynamic-library

I've recently installed Cygwin to my new work laptop and ever since I've being bombarded with the above Warning message like commercial advertisements whenever I execute commands that involves php scripts

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_tidy.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_tidy.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_tidy.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_tidy.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_tidy.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/tidy.dll' - No such process in Unknown on line 0
```

I've done all the research (online) I could to remove this message / fix the problem. Also I can confirm the missing libraries are in fact NOT MISSING. My cygwin install directory is C:\cygwin. Although I couldn't find /usr/lib in Windows Explorer (C:\cygwin\usr), I could, however find it as well as the libraries in cygwin. Lastly, I tried to add all paths for Windows (C:\cygwin\lib) and linux (/usr/lib) to their environment specific path variables. None of these worked.

This might seem nothing but noise as it doesn't stop me from executing php scripts on command line. But I pretty sure issues like these are never negligible in later stages of development.

Comment: Try a Google search like [Unable to load dynamic library](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable+to+load+dynamic+library&oq=Unable+to+load+dynamic+library&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

thanks Brett for his comment. When I did a search again, I found the following Stack-overflow page that answers my question
[Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)
The solution is around the following grep command suggested in one of the reply post

```
grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="
```

As soon as I run it I found the ini file where I could comment the correct extension to get rid of php_tidy.dll message

My issue request fixes in a 2nd place, so as an extension to the above grep command, I used

```
grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "tidy.dll"
```

which gave me the location another file that requires similar commenting.

Updated both files (php.ini and tidy.ini) rid of the messages. Now my output looked much cleaner.

A more appropriate solution is to install the missing libraries via apt-get, which was discussed in other post. But most of the discussion relates to missing .so files, I'm not sure what to "apt-get" for the dlls. For the time being, I'm happy where I am.