# Docker gd module for PHP 7

Tags: php, drupal, docker, docker-compose, drupal-8

I've got docker file, which is configured for Drupal 8, but after I fired up "docker-compose up", everything went smooth but in installation of Drupal it's showing me that "gd" module for PHP is not enabled.

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
# Install modules
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y vim curl wget build-essential software-properties-common git ca-certificates

RUN apt-get install -y \
    libbz2-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libvpx-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    && \

apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \

docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
        --with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
        --with-vpx-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && \

docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        bz2 \
        exif \
        ftp \
        gd \
        gettext \
        mbstring \
        mcrypt \
        mysqli \
        opcache \
        pdo_mysql \
        shmop \
        sockets \
        sysvmsg \
        sysvsem \
        sysvshm \
        zip \
    && \

    pecl install apcu memcached && \
    echo 'extension = apcu.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/apcu.ini && \
    echo 'extension = memcached.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

I try this method: [Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565521/error-in-php5-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)
But no use

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will help you

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Comment: Funny, this worked out for me but I had to add it to the entrypoint. It didn't work at all if I let it as a `RUN` command inside the `Dockerfile`...

Comment: `E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @chovy try `apt-get install libpng-dev`

Answer (score 7):

maybe should try this

```
# Install GD
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg62-turbo-dev
E: Unable to locate package libpng12-dev

Answer (score 6):

With PHP 7.2 I got the following error when trying the accepted/other answers:

> E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate

This worked for me:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN apt update \
    && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl pdo_mysql bcmath mbstring exif gd
```

Note the change from `libpng-dev12` to `libpng-dev`

Comment: configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update     && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl pdo_mysql bcmath mbstring exif gd' returned a non-zero code: 1