# Can't find intl php

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, intl

I'm running Xampp on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to get CakePhp to work.
After uncommenting the line corresponding to the extension in php.ini, I keep getting this message when running php:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I've tried multiple ways to solve that such as defining the extension path in php.ini and downloading intl with pecl but I can't get it to function proprely.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/10565521/5930557

Comment: These answers suggest to simply disable the extension but I actually need it for CakePhp to work, also, the extension is installed in both the extension folder of xampp and the scripts folder of apache2 so I really don't know what to do since  /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.so exists...

Comment: what version of php are you using? because php_intl packages are different for versions.

Answer (score 1):

Install intl extension by if your php version is 7.0

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

if your php version is 5.6 then run

```
apt-get install php56-intl
```

then restart your apache. hope your problem will be solve

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: it was trying to load a library that was already loaded via the command line (so no need for the shared object).
I commented the line in php.ini and everything went well, no more warnings and cakephp is working!